# If I redirect a URL to someone else's domain, how can I get Twitter/FB/etc. to recognize the meta info?

Tags: redirect, metadata

So within my .htaccess I redirect a non-existent directory to a 3rd party server in this manner, without a glitch.

```
Redirect 301 /clouds www.ibm.com/cloud/free
```

However, when I paste my link ***[www.example.com/clouds](http://www.example.com/clouds)*** in Twitter, FB, or other social media, it's just the link. If I paste the destination directory in the same social media page, any additional metadata pops up instead of a just a plain old link. *See attached image*

I've also read that different sites, read different metadata.

So is there any method to either get the tags, or do a redirect for the tags as well? Or is this something I have to wait for search engine crawlers to do when they finally hit my site?

[Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T95v.png)

Comment: Hello. I do not see an reference to Ubuntu in your question. what version are you using?

Comment: @David 18.04. I mention Ubuntu because I have noticed different linuxes do vary slightly